# Textview's value not updating while extending LinearLayout

Tags: android

I have my class which is extending `LinearLayout`.

Code snippet as below :

```
class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout{

static TextView  txt;
static Button btn;
static LayoutInflater inflater;

public MyLinearLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    View.inflate(context, R.layout.displayinfo, this);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)  getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
}

public  void change(){

     View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.displayinfo, null);
     //Button btn = (Button) inflate(context, R.id.btn, null);
     txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     Handler handler = new Handler() {
         @Override
         public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
             txt.setText("Changed");

         }
     };
     //view.refreshDrawableState();


}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    change();
}
}
```

But the value is not getting changed when `onDraw()`->`change()` method is getting called.
I am adding this view to `WindowManager`.

In this extended view I have to basically update values from an `array`. But the problem is how to call the loop continuously? Calling an `invalidate()` helps me to call it continuously but it increases the CPU usage as well as the view gets refreshed so fast that user cannot actually view the `View`.

so basically I have two problems:

1.`TextView` not getting updated in above code snippet?

2.How do we basically continuously update a views value without calling an `invalidate()` method ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Calling change won't change the text because inside of change() you have a handler, and you are overriding its handleMessage() by telling it to change the text. In order to actually make the change you'll need to send a signal to the Handler.

Try putting this line:

```
handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

in place of

```
//view.refreshDrawableState();
```

then the change method should actually set the text in the TextView.

**EDIT:** Also you probably shouldn't be inflating a new view every time you call change. In fact you don't need to inflate at all because you've already done it in the constructor (You already are the view you are trying to get a reference to). You should be able to call findViewById() without any reference in front of it, to get the TextView reference. You should be doing that in your constructor instead of inside change().

Comment: I tried putting handler.sendEmptyMessage(0); , but it doesn't works.
What cen be other ways to refresh the data in the view if we leave handler aside.